# How do you change the row names in a gt table?

Tags: r, gt

Is there a way to change the row names in a gt table?

For example, in the below table how would I change the row labeled "Europe" to "Europa?"

```
islands_tbl <- 
  tibble(
    name = names(islands),
    size = islands
  ) |>
  arrange(desc(size)) |>
  slice(1:10) 

islands_tbl |>
gt()
```

[image]

Even if this column is converted to a stub (see below code), there still appears to be no way to change the names of the row labels. The below is from the example in the intro documentation for the gt package.

```
# Create a gt table showing ten of the
# largest islands in the world; this
# time with a stub
gt_tbl <- 
  islands_tbl |>
  gt(rowname_col = "name")

# Show the gt table
gt_tbl
```

which produces the following table, but still with no option to change the row names...

[image]

I'm looking for something similar to the `cols_label()` function.

Thanks in advance for your help. I may be missing something obvious; apologies if so.

Again, to be clear, I would, for example, like to change the row label "Antarctica" to "A really cold place."

Comment: The row names come from what gt considers data, i.e. a column of values in your data frame, as opposed to the column names which are labels of the columns, not "data" themselves. So gt is expecting you to alter the value in the data frame itself if you want it to say "Europa" or something.

Comment: Thanks @joran It just seems to me there should be a simpler way. I have 21 values in that column and they are all row labels that have convenient names with underscores for EDA, but I need to change those names to create a presentation ready table. Creating a new column manually with those labels seems unreasonable. I already used the labelled package to label them which works with gtsummary. Just seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: I haven't used the **labelled** package much, though scanning it now it seems like an odd deficiency that there isn't a prominent way to convert a column with value labels into the labels themselves. But I think perhaps just creating a new column via `as.character(to_factor(name))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve your desired result would be via [`gt::text_replace`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/index.html#text-transformation) which allows to replace text including the row names based on a regex pattern:

```
library(gt)

islands_tbl |>
  gt() |> 
  text_replace(
    pattern = "^Antarctica$",
    replacement = "A really cold place."
  )
```

[image]

And in case of multiple replacements you could use `text_case_match` or `text_case_when`:

```
library(gt)

islands_tbl |>
  gt() |> 
  text_case_match(
    "Antarctica" ~ "A really cold place.",
    "Europe" ~ "Europa"
  )
```

[image]